# How to reuse a Redux store from inside a React library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two repositories split up like this:

`main-app`: A `create-react-app` project defining a redux store with some reducers.

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    reducer1: myReducer
});
const store = createStore(reducers);
const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And an `App` component returning `<AppHeader />` in the `render` method defined below, in my `lib-header` library.

`lib-header`: An external library using the main app's store, defined like this:

```
class AppHeader extends Component {
  render() {    
    return (
        <div>{this.props.isAuthenticated ? 'User authenticated' : 'User not authenticated'}</div>
    );
  }
}

AppHeader.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
    onSignin: PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSignin: () => dispatch(actions.signIn())
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppHeader);
```

However, when `lib-header` tries to use the `connect(...)` function, it generates this error:

*Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(e)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(e) in connect options.*

For some reasons, the store defined in the `Provider` of the main app does not get through to the external library, even though the `AppHeader` component is defined inside the `Provider` component of my main app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how external library is bundled and used, also on dependency versions. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. Redux versions may not match, or it could be something else.

Comment: Did you find out why that happened?